# How to reliably detect maximum additional CPUID levels?

Tags: assembly, cpuid

I would like to query CPU features using the `cpuid` instruction. I'm interested in all additional CPUID levels, including `0x80000000` and `0xc0000000` (Centaur). The problem is that I don't see a clear way of determining whether a particular level is supported.

In particular, I'm worried about this particular bit from [Intel(R) 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html):

> Two types of information are returned: basic and extended function information. If a value entered for CPUID.EAX
>   is higher than the maximum input value for basic or extended function for that processor then the data for the
>   highest basic information leaf is returned.

This means that if I query `cpuid` with `EAX = 0x80000000` or `EAX = 0xc0000000`, I can either get the maximum CPUID level in `EAX`, or output for some random basic level leaf.

Is there a reliable and relatively easy way of determining whether a particular level is supported?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with detecting processor vendor identification (12-character text string at level 0) and then continue basing on this value. For Intel, two range of levels, since 0 and 0x80000000, are supported (the first one is native Intel one and the second one is some option set for compatibility with AMD); for AMD, the same two ranges are supported but some bits can change their value; then, for other vendors, you may look their own ranges according to their documentation.